# PayPal plugin - Custom CSS

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal

I have the `Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution (Includes Express Checkout)` plugin option set up, and I'm wondering if it's possible to style the iFrame that is rendered:

[image: PayPal screenshot]

I've searched high and low for an answer but the PayPal documentation seems to send me round in circles.

Is there a way to upload custom CSS to PayPal? I know other card processors have this function.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?